# $v^2 = 2ax$ or $v^2 = ax$?

Tags: kinematics, integration, calculus

As far as I am aware, $v^2 = 2ax$ is the formula to find the velocity in various questions.

If kinetic energy = work,
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=Fx$$
$$mv^2=2max$$
$$v^2=2ax$$

We use this formula to solve some questions in school.
But when i just fiddle around with basic formulas i get this.

$$x/v = t$$
$$v/a = t$$
$$t = t$$
$$x/v = v/a$$
$$v^2 = ax$$

And this just confuses me. I assume that $x/v=t$ and $v/a=t$ is actually kind of simplified or else I cannot see why $v^2$ equals $ax$ on one and $2ax$ on the other.

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just do the calculus!

Comment: x=vt only for constant velocity - otherwise you need an integral. The other equation does not have constant velocity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second derivation, the correct formulas are

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\Delta x}{v} &\approx \Delta t &
\frac{\Delta v}{a} &\approx \Delta t
\end{align}$$

I'm sure you can easily find some examples to show you why $x/v = t$ and $v/a = t$ don't make any sense. Anyway, when you put these together, you get $v\Delta v \approx a\Delta x$, with the approximation becoming more accurate the smaller the $\Delta$s are.

Note that if you take the limit as $\Delta v$ and $\Delta x$ go to zero, then integrate, you get

$$\begin{align}
\int_{v_i}^{v_f} v\,\mathrm{d}v &= \int_{x_i}^{x_f} a\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\frac{v_f^2 - v_i^2}{2} &= a(x_f - x_i) \\
v_f^2 &= v_i^2 + 2a\Delta x
\end{align}$$

which is exactly the correct formula.