Explaining the equations of motion in kinematics
Hi I Have these equations and I don't know and understand what each of them means.
Can someone help me?
$$\tag 1 v=v_0+at$$
$$\tag 2 x=v_0t+\frac{at^{2}}{2}$$
$$\tag 3 v^{2}=v_0^{2}+2ax$$
What does each of them do at certain distance, acceleration and velocity?
At class the teacher didn't explain us  how each of these formulas work.

Is this of any help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161516/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287314/226902

@Quillo The link doesn't show a real life example...

It s just basic algebra and calculus, there is no physics here. It is a pure math exercise: I give you a prescribed formula for $v(t)=v_0+a t$, find the position $x(t)$. More on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

This question is about the very basics of calculus and the definitions of velocity and acceleration, and I don't think physics SE is the best place to learn these principles. I suggest you look into mechanics101 books which will give a more thorough explanation.  Just so you will not go completely empty handed from my comment, I will explain the first equation: v is the velocity of an object and $a$ is its acceleration, the rate of change of the velocity - the bigger $a$ is, the velocity will get bigger in the same amount of time (plug in the formula $a=1,t=1$ and $a=5,t=1$ and see $v$ grow)

@OfekGillon Îs mechanics101 a book?I can't find that on the internet.Does it Have another title?

@Taurus , "101" is a slang for meaning super-basics-introduction to something, see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/14266 . What I meant is look for the most basic course in mechanics in a college you know is good (maybe in your native language?) and open the first book in the bibliography of the course. Hope this helped

Just out of curiosity, where do you go to school?

At class the teacher didn't explain us how each of these formulas work. Have you considered asking your teacher for guidance on these?

A question like this is hard to answer, because there are at least five different interpretations of the question: "What do these equations mean, physically?", "How do I use these equations to solve a problem?", "What is the physical context in which these equations are applicable?", "What do the equations mean, mathematically?", "How do we derive these equations (geometrically, or with calculus?", etc. The question "What does each of them do at certain distance, acceleration and velocity?" is hard to understand, too, because equations don't do anything. Can you clarify?

@march This is the question which I meant:What is the physical context in which these equations are applicable?

The physical context is constant 1D acceleration, as Noob_Master_69’s answer stated. If $a$ isn’t a constant, then these equations don’t apply.

these are the equations of motion, valid in case of constant acceleration(a).
They are quite helpful in solving problems and questions.
First of all, you must know what the variables are here.
v = final velocity
u = initial velocity
s = displacement
t = time-taken
a = acceleration
Now the equations establish a very fine relation between these variables disregarding air resistance. Firstly, know what is given and what to be found out, then use the appropriate equation.

You tagged calculus, so the explanations are quite nice and short.
All of these are equations for constant acceleration, $\frac{dv}{dt} = a$.  If you integrate that equation, and set the constant of integration such that there is some defined initial velocity ($v(0) = v_0$), you get equation (1).  If you integrate it again, you almost get equation (2).  (2) actually isn't quite right.  It's missing the constant of integration.  We need to define some initial position, $x(0) = x_0$, and the correct equation would be $x = v_0t + \frac{at^2}{2} + x_0$.  As written, (2) is only right assuming $x_0 = 0$.
The third is called Torricelli's equation.  It's not a difficult proof, but it is a bit longer than simply doing an integration.  You end up doing a substitution between (1) and (2) to get to the final answer.  You will note that that Wikipedia page uses $\Delta x$ where your (3) just has $x$.  If you're not familiar, $\Delta x = x - x_0$.  Torricelli uses $\Delta x$ because his equation correctly handles $x_0$, while (2) does not.  Just a minor detail.
All of these simply fall from the definitions of velocity and acceleration, using integration.  They are useful because you don't always want to have to do an integral every time you want to calculate.  In the cases where one has constant acceleration, you can just stand on the shoulders of the 16th and 17th century physicists and borrow the simple algebraic equations they devised.

Lets say, you drive your car with certain velocity $~v_0~$ then you decide to accelerate your  car with  constant acceleration a for  the next ,5 seconds.
Equation (1), give you the final velocity that you obtain under these condition .
$$ v=v_0+a\,5$$
additionale you ask yourself which distance my car obtained unter these conditions .
$$x=v_0\,5+\frac{a\,5^2}{2}$$
Lets say, you drive your car with certain velocity $~v_0~$ then you decide to accelerate your  car with  constant acceleration a  for  the next $~500~$ meters . Equation (3), give you the final velocity that you obtained under these conditions.
$$v=\sqrt{v_0^2+2\,a\,500}$$

with
$$v=v_0+a\,t\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=\int v(t)\,dt\\
x=v_0\,t+\frac{a\,t^2}{2}\quad\Rightarrow\\
t_x=\frac{-v_0+\sqrt{v_0^2+2\,a\,x}}{a}$$
thus
$$v(x)=v_0+a\,t_x=\sqrt{v_0^2+2\,a\,x}$$
